# managing IB objects without iboutlets

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

i have got 24 buttons in my project.I need to manage them but I don't want to get my MainViewController polluted by 24 declarations of pointers, properties & synthesizes.

i was thinking about using buttonPushed functions and do it like:

```
> -(IBAction)buttonPushed:(id)sender{

> UIbutton *button=sender;

>[buttons addObjectAtIndex:[sender tag]];

>}
```

my question is:is sender a pointer to the IBObject?

edit:

I need to get a pointer to an object in interface builder which has not been clicked (so any (id)sender sent yet), what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sender parameter will contain your button that was pushed.
This design pattern was designed exactly for this, the case you have one method for multiple actions

Comment: ok.what to do if I need to identify buttons before an action was called?
example:i need to set image to a button which hasnt been clicked yet.

Comment: well, this is a much tougher problem as you can't an object to a method only action, However one solution I can think of is on "viewDidLoad" go over all of the subviews of the view and "find" these buttons by scanning the list and identifying them somehow

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sender is the IBObject that sent the buttonPushed message.  You can ask the sender (the button) for identifying information (such as the label) to decide what action to take.